# Twitter Bootstrap MVC Alternatives

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

After reviewing https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/ I found you had to pay for it.

Is there any free alternative or tuturiols around that allow you to make HTML helpers for bootstrap for thing like text boxes, check boxes, dropdowns etc?

I've tried creating simple HTML helpers but having issues even if i could override current HTML helpers like TextBoxFor but add classes and set how it should render this would be helpful.

An example of my first steps is within the Views folder i have created a folder named "EditorTemplates"

Within this folder i have added "string.cshtml" this is called for thing like TextBoxFor.

Within here i have:

```
@{
    var placeholder = string.Empty;
    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("placeholder"))
    {
        placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["placeholder"] as string;
    }
}
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { placeholder = placeholder, @class = "form-control"})
 </div>
```

This creates a bootstrap looking input item, but doesnt have the required flexibility such as parameteres.

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably off-topic: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` More on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Since bootstrap its really popular now, I think it is a good question

Comment: It is free only. Where did you see the license information?

Comment: https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/Download

Comment: The actual css/js is free but implementing it to MVC Helpers/HTML Helpers isnt.

Comment: This should be free :) anyway hope we can expect the same from open source community or from Microsoft Web Tools team :)

Comment: Exactly alot of people have started implementing alternatives and similar things so was looking for some good tuturiols, coding advice and some examples to get me started.

Comment: Its better to go with plain html, easy for changing the classes or structure  for bootstrap 4.x in future:)

Comment: I just feel doing the html on my own would ruin the benfit of MVC such as [Required] attrubiute where this fitlers thoruhg from database to UI when using entity framework with MVC

Comment: @LmC iI know this was closed by in case you care not aware, check out Chameleon Forms. https://github.com/MRCollective/ChameleonForms

Comment: Great will have a look!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the easiest thing to do is do the helper yourself, it's really not hard and you have full control on them, especially as you can reuse default helper calls, for example for a simple Boostrap textbox group you could have:

```
public static class BootstrapHtmlHelper
{    
    public static MvcHtmlString TextboxGroupFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        string title, 
        string id, 
        string placeholder)
    { 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        sb.AppendLine("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label>", id, title);
        sb.AppendLine( htmlHelper.TextBoxFor( expression, new { @class = "form-control", @id = id, @placeholder = placeholder }) );
        sb.AppendLine( htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor( expression );
        sb.AppendLine("</div>");
        return new MvcHtmlString( sb.ToString() );
    }
}
```

You can then add any parameters, check for the validation, add helper boxes, do any kind of formatting, etc.

Then you can use it in your views:

```
@Html.TextboxGroupFor(x => x.FirstName, "First Name", "first-name-id", "Enter first name...")
```

**Update:**

Example for a dropdown, simply reuse `ListBoxFor` and pass an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`:

```
public static class BootstrapHtmlHelper
{    
    public static MvcHtmlString DropdownGroupFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list,
        string selectedValue,
        string title, 
        string id)
    { 
        // Apply selected value to the list
        var selectedList = list.Select(x => x.Value.Equals(selectedValue) ? x.Selected = true : x.Selected = false);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"form-group\">");
        sb.AppendLine("<label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label>", id, title);
        sb.AppendLine( htmlHelper.ListBoxFor( expression, selectedList, new { @class = "form-control", @id = id }) );
        sb.AppendLine( htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor( expression );
        sb.AppendLine("</div>");
        return new MvcHtmlString( sb.ToString() );
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
@Html.DropdownGroupFor(
    x => x.Country, 
    Model.Countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    { 
        Text = x.Name, 
        Value = x.Id 
    }));
```

Comment: Must say i like this approach, Are you able to provide an example for a select/dropdown?   As this is the one cause most difficultiy?

Comment: I added an example above for list box, but do you have any specific difficulties with them? It's as easy as calling ListBoxFor instead of TextBoxFor.

Comment: You've actually nailed it! Yea i just couldnt get it looking good for the life of me! Will mark this correct tomorrow once implementing a small test. Thanks!

Comment: Im assuming i could do roughly the same for the begin form?

Comment: I don't remember having to do that for the BeginForm in any of my project as forms are pretty simple in Bootstrap, you simply have to add: new { @role = "form" } to the htmlAttributes parameter, and maybe @class="form-horizontal" and @class="form-inline" if you prefer those style.

Comment: I am getting htmlHelper does not exist in current context? Where do i get this from? Cant many examples for calling TextBoxFor from class and not Razor.

Comment: how about adding warning, error classes on the form-group when validation failed? and showing the error message?

Comment: invalid args for stringbuilder as well as missing htmlHelper

Answer (score 2):

you can create your own helpers for controls and consume them. Below is sample for input button custom helper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CustomHelpers
{
    public static class ButtonHelper
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Button(this HtmlHelper helper, String       displayText, String elementId, String cssClass, String onClick)
        {
            TagBuilder inputButton = new TagBuilder("input");
            inputButton.AddCssClass(cssClass);
            inputButton.MergeAttribute("value", displayText);
            inputButton.MergeAttribute("id", elementId);
            inputButton.MergeAttribute("type", "button");
            inputButton.MergeAttribute("onclick","" + onClick + "");

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(inputButton.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Add the namespace CustomHelpers in your views web.config file under  tag and there you go you have your helper in the intellisense You just need to rebuild your solution for helper to be available in your views.

Comment: I like this aswell, Its a greate example! But what about a dropdown orvalidation messages for example?